# Akka SyncWriteJournal no matching arguments

Tags: java, constructor, akka

So I have an `Akka` `SyncWriteJournal` (still in progress) and while unit testing the persistence I always get this error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no matching constructor found on class com.example.CustomJournal for arguments []`

I have one constructor for `CustomJournal` which takes a few arguments necessary for the persistence to work. If I add an empty constructor to solve the error message the test throws and NPE because it needs fields that should be initiated in the constructor.

Why does it call the empty constructor (I never do it) by itself? And how can I solve this problem?

Code:

Class which creates actors:

```
public class AkkaActors {

private final ActorSystem actorSystem;
private final ActorRef journal;
private final ActorRef akkaPersistence;

public AkkaActors(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    this.actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("akkaSystem");
    this.akkaPersistence = actorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(AkkaPersistence.class), "akkaPersistence");
    this.journal = actorSystem.actorOf(Props.create(CustomJournal.class, jdbcTemplate, objectMapper, actorSystem), "customJournal");
}
```

Akka persistence actor:

```
public class AkkaPersistence extends UntypedPersistentActor {

private final static String PERSISTENCE_ID = "persistent_actor";

public AkkaPersistence() {

}

@Override
public void onReceiveRecover(Object msg) throws Exception {
    if (msg instanceof String) {
        System.out.println("msg");
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceiveCommand(Object msg) throws Exception {
    if (msg instanceof String) {
        final String message = (String) msg;
        persist(message, new Procedure<String>() {
            @Override
            public void apply(String message ) throws Exception {
                getContext().system().eventStream().publish(message );
            }
        });
    } else {
        unhandled(msg);
    }
}

@Override
public String persistenceId() {
    return PERSISTENCE_ID;
}
```

}

Custom journal class (without contents of implemented methods):

```
public class CustomJournal extends SyncWriteJournal {

JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
ObjectMapper objectMapper;
ActorSystem actorSystem;

public CustomJournal(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, ObjectMapper objectMapper, ActorSystem actorSystem) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    this.actorSystem = actorSystem;
}
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
public class AkkaActorsTest{

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@Test
public void test() throws OperationNotSupportedException {
    AkkaActors actors = new AkkaActors(jdbcTemplate, objectMapper);
    actors.persist("test");
}
```

Comment: In looking at their docs for persistence, I'm going to take a guess here and say that your custom journal can not have constructor args.  If you configured your custom journal into the config file as `akka.persistence.journal.plugin`, then I'm guessing Akka itself is instantiating it and expecting it to have a no-args constructor.  You should look at the docs and how they show the `SharedLeveldbJournal` being insitialized as you will probably have to do something similar.

Comment: @cmbaxter Thanks for the tip. I did have a look and having the default constructor should be fine (Jackson also uses it) but I'm wondering then how to get the config (like ActorSystem, JdbcTemplate and ObjectMapper) into the object.

Comment: Usually these externally loaded "driver-like" entities expect a zero argument constructor, or at least a fixed set of arguments. Every other argument is passed via external configuration files that are used. As for system, since the journal is an Actor, you can get the system via context.system.